# Container only works while running from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, docker

I have got the sample `WeatherForecast` API in VS 2019 with Docker support. I build the solution and run it with Docker profile. I can see the image gets created in Docker Desktop, container is running and I can access the https://localhost:49181/weatherforecast URL.

But as soon as I stop running the solution from VS, that URL becomes inaccessible.

Any ideas what could be happening? Shouldn't I be able to access the API/URL once it's deployed in Docker and VS is not running?

Container is running even when VS has stopped
[image]

Comment: I assume that when you stop running it in VS, that VS stops the container.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but I can see that it is still running. Screenshot attached above.

Comment: The port in the screenshot is different from the one mentioned in your question.

Comment: yeah, sorry, that's just me trying to test by deploying again which ended up with a different port number. I have used the same port number.

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build#debugging)

TL;DR: When running the container from VS it only runs your actual process for F5 / Ctrl+F5. The container is left running so it can be reused for the next launch (although VS should kill the container on solution close).

If you instead build the full image (right-click on the Dockerfile) it will produce an image that does start your process when the container starts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completly sure how it works, but your container has :dev tag.
In my case solution was to switch from 'debug' to 'release' in visual studio Solutions configurations, and then started debugging. It created new image without 'dev' tag

[image: pic]